# Border between two ListViews

Tags: android, android-listview

I was looking of "*border*" between two ListViews as shown in the attached screenshot(in red) and not the border(in white) among the ListView items.

Any idea of how to set the border between the ListViews as shown?

[image]

Thanks,
Sana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a border on the sides, what I've typically seen done is to just add an empty View in between the ListViews in the layout. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This would give you a 1dp red border between the three ListViews.